# IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, mef, windows-10-universal

I use **MEF** to inject my dependencies, and I need to execute code right **after** the **dependecies are injected**.

I can't inject them in the constructor because it will end up in a circular dependencies problem.

In WPF, you could use the interface System.ComponentModel.Composition.IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification, with the method OnImportsSatisfied, which will be called after the depdencies are injected.

Is there a way to do the same thing in UWP?

Comment: The MEF used in UWP is a lightweight version of MEF, what you've used in WPF is not available in UWP.

Answer (score 0):

System.Composition has OnImportsSatisfiedAttribute (in assembly Assembly System.Composition.AttributedModel).

Used like so:

```
[OnImportsSatisfied]

public void OnImportsSatisfied()
{
}
```